# Play video in ubuntu terminal without GUI

Tags: command-line, server, video

So. I have this old laptop and I installed Ubuntu Server on it so I would have just the terminal to play with. Now I'm trying to play video without seeing/installing any GUI. I installed mplayer but mplayer needs a "display" (GUI?) to play video (no, ASCII-art isn't what I'm looking for)

Any suggestions? Is it possible to get mplayer working without any GUI?

PS
*I don't mind installing GUI but I want to be able to create a program where you enter a password and then see a video in fullscreen, without seeing any GUI (so looks like a hacker screen).*

Comment: why not just use i3 or another very-basic keyboard-centric gui without panel, borders, buttons or menu.   Bryan Lunduke wrote a series of articles about living in terminal (30days) but I don't recall covering video....

Answer (score -1):

You can use mplayer like so:

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
mplayer -vo caca <yourvideo>
```

Comment: @MichaelBay: Not with the `caca` output module.

Comment: This doesn't work. with caca output module it gives me the video in ASCII (which i explained, i don't want). any other module give me errors because there's no GUI installed (i'm guessing)